# Misunderstanding Oauth2 and twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

There is somthing that i can't understood. I'm trying to writte a simple app in android to post twitt's into my account. I registered my app in dev.twitter. There i got an api(consumer) key/secret, and access token/access secret pairs. BUT, as in the [example](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth), i must use setOauthConsumer(cons key, cons secret) then, after that in the app I must use get getOAuthAccessToken to get oauth access token. But i'm alredy have this(!), so i can use acces token and secret directly, or what?

p. s. i know twitter4j.org examples, and i can use other resources, but i cant find the answer, so i'm posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i must use setOauthConsumer(cons key, cons secret) then, after that in
>   the app I must use get getOAuthAccessToken to get oauth access token.
>   But i'm alredy have this(!), so i can use acces token and secret
>   directly, or what?

We need the following 4 values for every request to `twitter API`:

1. Consumer key
2. Consumer Secret
3. Access Token
4. Access Token Secret

You already have the following values:

1. Consumer key
2. Consumer Secret

Access Token & Access Token Secret are fetched in following two ways:

**Case 1:** Configuration required for app-only auth, to fetch the twitter feeds even
        without Logging in to twitter account.

As you have not logged in, the `twitter4j` gives the `OAuth2Token` (access token and token secret) using `getOAuth2Token();`
Then you use these values in your configuration of `Twitter` instance. No need to store these values. You can get them using `getOAuth2Token()` for every request.

**Case 2:** When you login using your credentials.

In this case, the request is sent to `Twitter API` to get access token and access token secret (values are generated at the time of registering your application on `Twitter`).

Once you get these values, store it in `SharedPrefernces` and use them in subsequent requests. No need to request them again and again.

I hope this helps you.